# How can I change the color of a single div with every mouseover event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid of divs. I want each div to change color gradually from grey to black on every mouse over - specifically, I want the box to become black by the 10th mouseover event. I'm halfway there. As it stands, I have a function implementing this color gradient, but after a single box becomes black, all of the other boxes that I mouseover are also black. How can I make each box start on the same shade of grey? I bet I can achieve this through a very long series of `if` statements, but I want to know if there is a more concise solution.

```js
const bigContainer = document.querySelector('.bigContainer')

window.onload = function initializeGrid() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        bigContainer.innerHTML+='<div class="row">';

        for(let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            bigContainer.innerHTML+='<div class="smallBox">';
        }
    }
}

let rbgPercentValue = 90;

bigContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    let target = event.target
    let rgbColor = `rgb(${rbgPercentValue}%,${rbgPercentValue}%,${rbgPercentValue}%)`

    if (target !== bigContainer) {
      target.style['background'] = rgbColor;
      rbgPercentValue -= 10;
    }

})
```

```css
.smallBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.row {
    margin-bottom: -5px; 
}
.bigContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigContainer"></div>
```

Comment: _"but after a single box becomes black, all of the other boxes that I mouseover are also black"_ - Because there's only one `rgbPercentValue` (-> [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*))

Comment: You need to track a mouseOver count (or a colour/percentage) for each element

Comment: @Andreas `rbgPercentValue -= 10;`?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava One variable for all elements instead of one "variable" for every `.smallBox`...

Comment: @DBS How can I do that? I haven't been able to find a way to count mouseover events on Google

Comment: Use CSS (one class for every iteration), use a `data-*` attribute (see my first comment), use an array where you store the current value for a `.smallBox`, ...

Comment: you may try to add an id for each small box while you create them in the for loop. later add a data- attribute for the target small box, (unique by its id), which is its rgb value.

Comment: Either store it in JS (A variable for each element, or an array of values) or add it to the elements themselves using data attributes (Andreas linked to the documentation for those in an above comment)

Comment: @DBS I'm not quite sure what you mean. I read through the documentation that Andreas posted but don't see how it's applicable, probably because I know too little. would you mind posting a solution?

Comment: Store the current value for a `.smallBox` in a `data-*` attribute and use this to generate the new color on `mouseover`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A demo using title (percentage is also visible).

```js
const bigContainer = document.querySelector('.bigContainer')

window.onload = function initializeGrid() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        bigContainer.innerHTML+='<div class="row">';

        for(let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            bigContainer.innerHTML+='<div class="smallBox">';
        }
    }
}

bigContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
let target = event.target
let rbgPercentValue = parseInt(target.dataset.percent);
if (isNaN(rbgPercentValue)) rbgPercentValue = 100;
if (rbgPercentValue >= 10) {
    rbgPercentValue -= 10;
    target.dataset.percent = rbgPercentValue;
}
    let rgbColor = `rgb(${rbgPercentValue}%,${rbgPercentValue}%,${rbgPercentValue}%)`

    if (target !== bigContainer) {
        target.style['background'] = rgbColor;
    }

})
```

```css
.smallBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.row {
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}
.bigContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="bigContainer"></div>
```

Comment: This is good, but you must try to edit it to use a custom `data-` attribute as `title` has a specific use in html

Comment: This is really interesting. @Tom I understand everything about this except for WHY ```target``` has the ```percent``` attribute. How does it end up there and how does it get the name "percent?"

Comment: Very simple ;-) Percentage must be be separate for each element and dataset attribute is of your (my here) choice. For example here some info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```js
const bigContainer = document.querySelector('.bigContainer')

window.onload = function initializeGrid() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        bigContainer.innerHTML+='<div class="row">';

        for(let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            bigContainer.innerHTML+='<div class="smallBox" data-rgb-percent-value="90">';
        }
    }
}

bigContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    const target = event.target
    const rgbPercentValue = target.dataset.rgbPercentValue;
    const rgbColor = `rgb(${rgbPercentValue}%,${rgbPercentValue}%,${rgbPercentValue}%)`

    if (target !== bigContainer) {
      target.dataset.rgbPercentValue = parseInt(target.dataset.rgbPercentValue) - 10;
      target.style['background'] = rgbColor;
    }
})
```

See live demo here: https://repl.it/repls/LivelySugaryStatistics

As others have suggested, this stores the color percentage with a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) for each individual block, rather than in a single global value.

Answer (score 0):

a little messy but this looks like it should work for you.

```js
const bigContainer = document.querySelector('.bigContainer')
var rbgPercentValue = 100;
var rbgMultiplier=.9;
var rbgbcolor=`rgb(${100}%,${100}%,${100}%)`;

var pcts =new Array(16);
for(let i=0;i<16;i++){
pcts[i] = new Array(16);
}

for(let i = 0;i<16;i++){
   for(let j = 0;j<16;j++){
      pcts[i][j]=100;
}
}


window.onload = function initializeGrid() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        bigContainer.innerHTML+='<div class="row">';

        for(let j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            bigContainer.innerHTML+='<div class="smallBox"  id=R'+i+'C'+j +'>';
        }
    }
}



bigContainer.addEventListener('mouseover', event => {
    let target = event.target
    
    
    var id= event.target.id;
    var index = id.indexOf("C");
    var row =id.substring(1,index);
    var col = id.substring(index+1);
    
    
    
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if (row != ''){
    
     pcts[row][col] = pcts[row][col]*rbgMultiplier;  
     rbgcolor=`rgb(${pcts[row][col]}%,${pcts[row][col]}%,${pcts[row][col]}%)`;

    
      div.style['background'] = rbgcolor;
    }
  
})
```

```css
.smallBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.row {
    margin-bottom: -5px; 
}
.bigContainer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="bigContainer"></div>
</body>
```